# IOS app wouldn't launch due to error "ld: 34 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I tried doing a clean build, uninstalling/reinstalling pods, not too sure where to go to next.

I never received this error before, but I first got it when I tried integrating Firebase into my project. I made sure to add all of the correct pods, I then went ahead and added a few other Firebase pods, just in case. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this, but here is what my pods file looks like.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Effortflex' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!
  # Pods for Effortflex

  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

end
```

Here is a sample of the error...

```
    /Users/owner1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Effortflex-bmtqbbukvlosxpbraqoiwplpcfyj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_encode.o
duplicate symbol '_pb_encode_fixed32' in:
    /Users/owner1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Effortflex-bmtqbbukvlosxpbraqoiwplpcfyj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_encode 2.o
    /Users/owner1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Effortflex-bmtqbbukvlosxpbraqoiwplpcfyj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_encode.o
ld: 34 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: `use_modular_headers!` and `use_frameworks!` are not intended to be used together.  `use_frameworks!` implies modular headers.

Comment: I made the change, but that did nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something that helped me was to the following -

1. In terminal navigate to your project folder
2. Run 'pod deintegrate'
3. Run 'pod install'

After that my project was able to compile. Hope that works for you!